# Wordpress 1st. level and sub level menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, submenu

I have designed a WP website, and I have put the navigation in a widget area on the left side. That's all good.

The navigation shows all 1st. level and sub level menu. That's all good too.

The problem is, when I click/activate a 1st. level menu. All the sub level menus for that 1st. level are automaticaly highlighted. Any ideas on how to remove the submenu highlight, when I click the parrent 1st. level menu?

The website is build with Headway.

See the website here: http://gaarde.cashosting.dk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS rule for each of the submenu items is

```
#block-bis5492b161af3aa ul li.current_page_item a
```

Which is applying the blue colour, and will make every child item of li.current_page_item blue.

Just insert `>` between li.current_page_item and a - this will only apply to the first child element.

So you'll have as your CSS rule:

```
#block-bis5492b161af3aa ul li.current_page_item > a
```

Comment: Thanks! When I disabled the system generated selected-color, and applied your rule, it works on both menu and sub-menu. I think I need to brush up a little on my css :-)

Answer (score 1):

Define exactly where the highlight will affect

```
ul.menu > li.current-menu-item > a{
   color: #4e9ca0;
}

ul.sub-menu > li.current-menu-item > a{
   color: #4e9ca0;

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This actually helped me on a different problem. But in this case, the sub-menu was still highlighted when a menu was clicked.